# GridLayout android

Tags: android

Можно ли сделать такой дизайн через GridLayout, чтобы на последней строке кнопки центрировались?
Можно ли сделать добавление динамически?

[image]

Comment: Беглый поиск результатов не дал... Думаю, придется переопределять GridView, и делать самому...

Comment: как бы вы делали такой layout?

Comment: @gcoder, пробовали для последних двух элементов выставлять значение `gravity` в виде `bottom|center`?

Answer (score 1):

Проще и быстрее будет написать свой алгоритм размещения вьюшек на scrollView (если это все скролится). Размеры экрана мы можем получить, как и размеры вьюшек. Остальное - математика, при этом вы сами сможете контролировать расстояния между вьюшками + profit.